# TYPO3 GeneralStorageFolder is gone, how to get storagePID inside plugin-flexform?

Tags: typo3

Good morning

In TYPO3 7.4 the "General Storage Folder" was kicked. Before this you could use the General Storage Folder inside a plugin-flexform. You could do things like

```
<settings.type>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>Betriebsart</label>
        <config>
           <type>select</type>
           <items type="array"></items>
           <allowNonIdValues>1</allowNonIdValues>
           <multiple>1</multiple>
           <maxitems>99</maxitems>
           <minitems>0</minitems>
           <size>10</size>                 
           <foreign_table>tx_enzhotellist_domain_model_type</foreign_table>
           <foreign_label>name</foreign_label>
           <foreign_table_where>AND sys_language_uid = 0 AND tx_enzhotellist_domain_model_type.pid=###STORAGE_PID###</foreign_table_where>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.type>
```

It was possible to access the values inside General Storage Folder with help of ###STORAGE_PID###. But now this way is gone, kicked off, obsolete, whatever... Sad - really sad.

So I ask you, how to access storagePid inside plugin-flexform? (btw: typoscript-settings do not help here!)

kind regards
Johannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get this field back as it has been removed. However you can use multiple other ways, described in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#columns-select-properties-foreign-table-where).

- `###CURRENT_PID###` - is the current page id (pid of the record).
- `###SITEROOT###`
- `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID###` - a value you can set from Page TSconfig dynamically.
- `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_IDLIST###` - a value you can set from Page TSconfig dynamically.
- `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_STR###` - a value you can set from Page TSconfig dynamically.

Comment: Okay, thank you.
So I set in pageTS:

TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 56

and changed the markers inside the flexform to ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID### and it worked.

Comment: I'd like to add that it's possible to define those markers for certain plugins only, which makes it less likely to disturb other plugin: TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.my_ext_pi1.sDEF.myField.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 56